# Hidden points in polygons

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, discrete-mathematics, plane-geometry

Let $h(n)$ be the largest number of mutually invisible points that can be located in a
polygon $P$ of $n$ vertices. Two points $x$ and $y$ are mutually invisible if the segment
$xy$ contains a point strictly exterior to the closed set $P$.

   [image: Hidden456]
I have a vague sense that this question—*What is $h(n)$*?—may have been studied before, and perhaps even entirely resolved, but I am not recalling references. Any help would be appreciated—Thanks!

---

**Answered** by Wlodek Kuperberg:

 [image: HiddenN]
The same construction shows that $h(n)=n-3$ for hiding points in a 
polyhedron of $n$ vertices in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: If $k$ points are mutually invisible in an $n$-sided poygon, then no two of them lie in the same triangle of a triangulation. Therefore $h(n)\le n-2$, and there is a simple example, generalizing your construction for $n=4$ and $5$, of an $(n+2)$-sided polygon with $n$ mutually invisible points in it, for every $n$: Draw a concave-up arc of a circle tangent to your "V" at its upper ends and place $n$ vertices on it. Place your red points very close to the midpoints of the chords of the circular arc. Unless I misinterpret your question, this shows that $h(n)=n-2$ for every $n\ge3$.

Comment: @WlodekKuperberg: Ah, *Yes*!, simply a reflex chain of $n-2$ edges, completed with two more edges. Nice proof---Thanks!

Comment: @WlodekKuperberg, you should write that as an answer!

Comment: @W.K.--you have provided examples of polygons for which convex coverings cannot have fewer members than any triangulation; an example for each number of sides.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OK - following the suggestion of Mariano Suárez-Alvarez, a moderator - I post my comment as an answer:

If k points are mutually invisible in an n-sided poygon, then no two of them lie in the same triangle of a triangulation. Therefore $h(n)≤n−2$, and there is a simple example, generalizing your construction for $n=4$ and $5$, of an $(n+2)$-sided polygon with $n$ mutually invisible points in it, for every $n$: Draw a concave-up arc of a circle tangent to your "V" at its upper ends and place $n$ vertices on it. Place your red points very close to the midpoints of the chords of the circular arc. Unless I misinterpret your question, this shows that $h(n)=n−2\ \ $ for every $n≥3$.